# no archive symbol table when using Android static library

Tags: android, c, static-libraries, toolchain

I am trying to compile some `C` files in an Android project. This need a `.a` static library that I compiled with Android toolchain.

Here's the `Android.mk` file

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := my_module
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := /somepath/include
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := some_c_file.c \
jfftw_Wisdom.c
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := fftw3
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -lz -lm /somepath/lib/somelib.a
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The problem is that I get this error

```
no archive symbol table (run ranlib)
```

Following some `SO` post, I tried to recompile the static library this `export AR=arm-linux-androideabi-ar`